# Limit of $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin (x)+\cos (3x)}{x+2}\;\;?$

Tags: calculus, limits

What is the value of $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin (x)+\cos (3x)}{x+2}\;\;?$$

All I can comment on this is that the denominator will increase  to infinity while the expression $\sin (x)+\cos (3x)$ will be at most $2$ , since for all $x$ values $-1\leq \sin x\leq 1$ and the same goes for cosine function.

What is the value of this limit?

The answer is $0$.

Comment: Squeezing.${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: In fact the question is like that : "Find the value of this limit." How can we find the value,instead of proving it to be 0 ?

Comment: It is clear from your post that you saw that the limit is $0$, and basically why.  In general, even for nicely convergent sequences, the value of the limit is usually quite unobvious. OK, maybe it is not clear that you saw. The guy on top can't more past $2$. and the bottom is blowing up. So for large $x$ the ratio is near $0$.

Comment: Thanks,so for such a question this conclusion is the solution,instead of an analytical solution.

Comment: It depends. In an "analysis" course you would be expected to provide full "$\epsilon$-$N$" detail. In an informal level calculus course, it would probably enough for you to show that you knew what was hapenning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By the Squeeze Theorem, we have

$$\dfrac 0{x+2} = 0 \leq \left| \frac{\sin x + \cos 3x}{x + 2}\right| \leq \frac{|\sin x| + |\cos 3x|}{x + 2} \leq \frac{2}{x + 2}$$

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} 0 = 0$$
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac 2{x + 2} = 0$$

Therefore, $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sin x + \cos 3x}{x + 2} = 0$$

Comment: Thanks,it is nice and clear for me.

Comment: an absolute value is always $\ge0$, so you probably didn't need the $\frac0{x+2}$ :-)

Comment: @amWhy: Nice to get that feedback! +1

Answer (score 2):

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given and choose $N$ such that $x > N \implies \frac{2}{x + 2} < \epsilon$. Then

$$\left| \frac{\sin x + \cos 3x}{x + 2} - 0\right| \leq \frac{|\sin x| + |\cos 3x|}{x + 2} \leq \frac{2}{x + 2} < \epsilon$$

for all $x > N$. Thus, the limit is $0$ as desired. I will leave it to you to give an explicit $N$ in terms of $\epsilon$.

Comment: I'm totally unfamiliar to this solution.But thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: @guest: this is an epsilon-delta proof. You will encounter them shortly if you haven't already.